# Percorrer matriz 4x4 com for, não entendi

Tags: c, matriz

Não entendi esse código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=1; i<5; i++) {
        for(j=1; j<5; j++) {
            if(i==j)
                printf("1 ");
            else
                printf("0 ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ele atribui valor 1 caso seja verdadeiro e 0 para falso, mas se as duas são iguais, não entendi, porque apenas uma linha vertical 1. e não tudo 1.

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Na **1ª** iteração do **1º** **for** o valor da variável **i** é **1**.
- Assim que entra neste **for** entra-se em um segundo **for** (que esta dentro do primeiro) o valor de sua variável **j** também é **1** logo será impresso 1.
- Nas próximas iterações o valor do **j** do segundo **for** não baterá com o do **1º** **for** pois o valor do **i** ainda não foi alterado pois ainda não se completou uma iteração do **1º** **for**.
- Assim que se completar a **1ª** iteração no **1º** **for** o valor do **i** será incrementado para **2** e o valor só batera com o do **j** quando o **2º** estiver na segunda iteração, imprimindo **1**. E assim sucessivamente.
- Logo os valores das variáveis contadoras de cada **for** só serão iguais quando ambos estiverem na mesma iteração (quando ambos **for** **externo** e **interno** estiverem na **1ª**, **2ª**, **3ª** e **4ª** iteração)